# How do I update a HTML Glossary

Tags: php, html, glossary

I have a Glossary of terms in an HTML file.
I want to create a form (or page) where I can add to the glossary without editing the HTML directly.
The user should just enter the word and description and press Update.

Is this possible without Javascript or a SQL database?

Comment: Did your data needs to persist when the user close the tab ? If not, you may use session variables. If so, you could read and write into a text file, but the use of MySQL would be much easier.

Comment: You could use localstorage in the browser if you don't care about other users being able to see the updates. Depends on the scenario. But that would require JavaScript to use, so maybe violates your first restriction. A database would make the most sense - what's your objection to using one? Even if you don't have a full DB server like MySQL available to you, you could use something simple like SQLite which is a file-based database.

Comment: I need to put the glossary on a Sharepoint site and was told not to use Javacript. Using SQLite seems to be a good option but I have no experience with that. I am willing to learn it though.

Comment: You want to put it on sharepoint? Well why not use a Sharepoint List as the data store, and maybe a simple power app to maintain it? (Or you can even just edit the list via the default sharepoint list UI). And then you can display the list contents in the sharepoint site, job done. Not sure why you'd mess about with PHP or JS for something like that in sharepoint

Comment: I would need to get access to our Sharepoint. But that was my first thought. I would most likely do that as doing it the way I asked seems like a hassle.

Comment: Well you'd need to get access to Sharepoint anyway even to do it the way you suggested originally, because you'd still need to upload the HTML pages etc. So I don't think your situation is any different in that respect.